# python pandas normalize column with keras, then splitting to groups

Tags: python, pandas, keras

Having the following data frame (actual data frame contains multiple strings and numeric columns):

```
col1    col2
0   A   10
1   A   10
2   B   5
3   B   5
```

I want to normalize the data based on column values so the result would look like this:

```
    col1    col2
0   A           0.632456
1   A           0.632456
2   B           0.316228
3   B           0.316228
```

And then split it to groups to get:

```
    col1    col2
0   A           0.632456
1   A           0.632456

    col1    col2
0   B           0.316228
1   B           0.316228
```

Splitting to groups is easy however I'm struggling with the normalization. I've tried using the following code:

```
from keras.utils import normalize
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["A","A","B","B"],"col2":[10,10,5,5]})
normalize(df, axis=0)
```

But since I have strings it fails, it will work if the values of A and B would be numeric.

Q: How can I normalize the numeric values by columns without dropping the string columns so I can later group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with categorical data, you should be looking at encoding methods such as a [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). It doesn't make sense to try to normalize these columns directly. In this case, you could use a scaler such as `MinMaxScaler` for the numerical columns (or keras' `Normalize`), and then one hot encode the categorical columns as:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder

sc = MinMaxScaler()
oh = OneHotEncoder()

col2_norm = sc.fit_transform(df.col2.to_numpy()[:,None])
col1_one_hot = oh.fit_transform(df.col1.to_numpy()[:,None]).toarray()

np.concatenate([col1_one_hot, col2_norm], axis=1)
array([[1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

If you just want to normalize the categorical column, you can just feed a `Series` to the scaler, rather than the entire dataframe:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler()
df['col2'] = sc.fit_transform(df.col2.to_numpy()[:,None])
```

Or similarly with keras' `normalize`:

```
df['col2'] = normalize(df.col2.to_numpy()).squeeze()
```

---

```
print(df)

  col1  col2
0    A   1.0
1    A   1.0
2    B   0.0
3    B   0.0    ​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is not what I'm looking for. I don't really care about the categorical column, I just use it to get the relevant sequences.  What I need it the numeric column normalized

Comment: Well just scale the series in question @ShlomiSchwartz ? Updated the answer